# how to select and merge records with some duplicate data and append

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stumbling on the logic trying to accomplish something that sounds rather simple but I can't get my head around on how to do it.

I have a table with Users that has "UserID" and "GroupID". Users can belong to several groups, so they can be in the table multiple times.

I also have a table that contains the content for the different groups "GroupContentTable" with "UserTimeFrame", "GroupID", "Content1", "Content2", "Content3".

The problem I am having is that if a user belongs to only one group, I want to output 3 "Contents" that belong to that group for the user, if a user belongs to two groups, I want to output 2 of one group and 1 of the other for the user, and if they belong to 3 groups I want to display 3 contents but only one of each group.

I was thinking something along the lines (sorry, not that well versed in SQL)

```
SELECT u.UserID, CASE u.GroupID
    WHEN 'GroupID' == 'Group1' AND 'c.UserFrequency' ==1 THEN 'c.Content1' AND 'Content2' AND 'Content3' END  , c.UserTimeFrame, c.Content1, c.Content2, c.Content3
FROM UserTable u INNERJOIN UserContentTable c
ON u.GroupID = c.GroupID
```

I was thinking about joining the table and using the CASE statement to set different conditions but it started to fall all apart.

This is what I have:

## UserTable

```
UserID | GroupID
ID1    | Group 1
ID1    | Group 2
ID2    | Group 3
ID1    | Group 3
ID3    | Group 2
ID3    | Group 3
```

## GroupContentTable

```
GroupID | UserTimeSpan | Content1    | Content2    | Content3
Group1  | 1            | UserTxt11   | UserTxt12   | UserTxt13
Group2  | 1            | UserTxt21   | UserTxt22   | UserTxt23
Group3  | 1            | UserTxt31   | UserTxt32   | UserTxt33
Group1  | 2            | UserTxt121  | UserTxt122  | UserTxt123
```

I would like to output this:

## OutputTable

```
UserID | UserTimeSpan | UserContent1 | UserContent2 | UserContent3
ID1    | 1            | UserTxt11    | UserTxt21    | UserTxt31
ID2    | 1            | UserTxt31    | UserTxt32    | UserTxt33
ID3    | 1            | UserTxt21    | UserTxt22    | UserTxt31
```

The join will output a row for each user, so for User ID1, there will be 3 rows but I want it to output only 1 row with the appropriate content according to their GroupID.

I am not sure if that is even possible. I am open to even change the structure.

Answer (score 0):

First do a `cross join` like this, and eliminate invalid rows:

```
select *
from (select u.UserID u1, u.GroupID g1, g.GroupID g2, g.*
from UserTable u
cross join GroupContentTable g) t
where t.g1 = t.g2;
```

You'll end up with a table like this:

```
UserID | GroupID | GroupID | UserTimeSpan | Content1    | Content2    | Content3
ID1    | Group 1 | Group1  | 1            | UserTxt11   | UserTxt12   | UserTxt13
ID1    | Group 2 | Group2  | 1            | UserTxt21   | UserTxt22   | UserTxt23
ID2    | Group 3 | Group3  | 1            | UserTxt31   | UserTxt32   | UserTxt33
ID1    | Group 3 | Group3  | 1            | UserTxt31   | UserTxt32   | UserTxt33
ID3    | Group 2 | Group2  | 1            | UserTxt21   | UserTxt22   | UserTxt23
ID3    | Group 3 | Group3  | 1            | UserTxt31   | UserTxt32   | UserTxt33
```

Now it is up to you how to move things around here, you can use a temp table with multiple update statements.

But I think you need to change GroupContent table design. I would have each content take its own row, and then if you need to group them have a column for group. This will make your querying much much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this...

```
SELECT 
    U.UserID,
    G.UserTimeSpan,
    G.GroupID,
    G.Content1,
    G.Content2,
    G.Content3 ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY G.UserTimeSpan,U.UserID ORDER BY G.UserTimeSpan,U.UserID,G.GroupID ) AS CNT
INTO TempTable
FROM @UserTable U 
     JOIN @GroupContentTable G ON G.GroupID = U.GroupID 

SELECT 
        UserID,
        UserTimeSpan,
        Content1,
        ISNULL((SELECT Content1 FROM TempTable WHERE UserID = C.UserID AND UserTimeSpan = C.UserTimeSpan AND CNT = C.CNT +1 AND (SELECT CNT FROM TempTable WHERE UserID = C.UserID AND UserTimeSpan = C.UserTimeSpan AND CNT = C.CNT +2) = 3) ,Content2) AS 'Content2',
        ISNULL(ISNULL((SELECT Content1 FROM TempTable WHERE UserID = C.UserID AND UserTimeSpan = C.UserTimeSpan AND CNT = C.CNT +2) ,(SELECT Content1 FROM TempTable WHERE UserID = C.UserID AND UserTimeSpan = C.UserTimeSpan AND CNT = C.CNT +1)),Content3) AS 'Content3'

FROM TempTable C
WHERE CNT=1
DROP TABLE TempTable
```